# What more details does my question need?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

My question here has been closed: [How can I increase the range of an EMP device?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/506764/how-can-i-increase-the-range-of-an-emp-device)

What more details does it need?

Comment: Seriously? You ask for help in intentionally damaging a device belonging to another person that, to use your own works "could be inside the skin" - and you wonder why you receive a negative reaction???

Comment: This is another case for poorly prompted questions with essential ingredients to be included before acceptance.ma list of preformatted forms would seriously help coach the unskilled writers.

Answer (score 9):

The question is similar to saying "How do I add 200HP to my car?" We need to know what type of car, what engine it has and diagrams for the car. The question was closed because we don't even know what kind of circuit you have. I'm not sure that many users would want to answer a question on how to improve a destructive device (although it is not off topic to ask questions about dangerous things).

And as always, if you put some time into writing a well thought out question with proper documentation (use the schematic tool), you'll get good answers. It looks like it took a minute or two to write that question, sometimes I'll take 20 minutes or more to write a well thought up question with proper circuits and a good summary of what I have tried and what does and doesn't work about the circuit.

You have posted several links, links are not good for questions, half of the people here won't click on them and when the link changes, the question is dead. A good question doesn't use links

Comment: Why do posters forget that while they can post relevant or not relevant questions, there is no guarantee that the questions **must** be answered. No person on here is being paid so none of us **have** to respond to any question.

Comment: People, by nature, are forgetful

Comment: People by nature are hopeful is more accurate.